# /search-results page returns 404 if no query parameter is present

Tags: search

I have inherited a Drupal site with a node that uses /search-results as path alias.

The page works fine if I use https://example.com/search-results?keys=test or https://example.com/search-results?keys, but it returns a 404 error if I use https://example.com/search-results.

Any thoughts on where to begin?

Answer (score 0):

How do you process the parameter? Is there a module to look at it? or you do it in your `.theme` hooks?

In any case you wanna try to set a default respose for the function you are using to process that `key` parameter.

Comment: That is a very good question. I've checked the .theme and didn't see anything.
There is a search api module installed which I am not familiar with.
The search form (on all pages) has an action for '/search-result', on that page, it says it is for an override of main view template and it uses 'exposed.keys' with comment: "exposed: Exposed widget form/info to display."
From there, i cannot see why this page would end up with a 404 error if that query parameter is not included.

Comment: Did you know if ther's a view named `search-results` or something like that?

Comment: this is what i can see:

there is a template in the theme named: page--search-result.html.twig
it contains an embed view (set in the .theme file) named views-view--search-content.html.twig.
if that embedded view is commented out in the page--search-result.html.twig the page will load (obviously without any results) 
as soon as it is added back in, the 404 occurs even if nothing is on that embedded page.

Comment: it looks like it is using a built in filter Views->Search Content -> FILTER CRITERIA Configure filter criterion: Search: Fulltext search has 'keys' as the Filter identifier

Comment: In this configuration, did you see any `CONTEXTUAL FILTERS` under the `ADVANCED` tab?